# Change height of window title bar for Visual Studio 2013 and/or Office applications

Tags: window, visual-studio-2013, titlebar

I don't know why but Microsoft decided to make the title bars of the windows of Visual Studio 2013 and Office applications huge! They are so thicker than normal windows and this is really annoying especially if you have a small screen.

Do you think there is a way to change this?

Comment: They are not bigger than normal, the color just blends with the menu bar background so it merely looks bigger.

Comment: Do you have your fonts set to large for high dpi screens?  This will make title bars look much bigger.

Comment: In VS 2015 the title bar is clearly taller and does not follow windows global title bar size.

Comment: @Hans, you can see the heights 2012, 2013, (2015 is similar) in the example on the right  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extension for Visual Commander to [hide Visual Studio 2013 title bar](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#hide_title_bar). In the HideTitleBar function instead of setting visibility to collapsed you can try to change height.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the size of the title bar. The best you can do is to auto-hide it, that way you see the ribbon only when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension of Visual Studio https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4bb76b8a-cef1-4223-8f9c-8e815e50e56c for download.

It can change the title bar smaller instead of hiding it. Because if you hide it, you loose the control to move the window around or minimize it.