# Huge title bar in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

This might not be a question appropriate for stack (More of a Win8/VS13 question). But is there an easy way to eliminate the huge title bar from a maximized, floated code window in VS2013 / Win 8.1?

See the red section:

[image: huge title bar]

I've got all of the other UI elements in my Win8 installation configured as I want, but they seem to have little or no effect on this one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using high dpi setting for your fonts?

Comment: One possible solution: [Change height of window title bar for Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20779635/2802841)

Comment: You've found some useful space for the menu and toolbar!